# Javascript Visual studio template for sharepoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript

Hello am looking for the best visual studio javascript template to code a customized sharepoint online action for a document library.  I am starting using the below link from the microsoft tech website:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/custom-actions-sharepoint-add-in

However, I don't have a licence for sharepoint designer but I am using visual stuido hence I am hoping to find a already existing javascript to get started.

Answer (score 0):

To add a Ribbon custom action to the SharePoint Add-in project

1. Right-click the SharePoint Add-in project, and choose Add > New Item> Office/SharePoint >  Menu Item Custom Action/Ribbon Custom Action.
2. Input the custom action name and choose Add.
3. The wizard asks you a series of questions to create it.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/create-custom-actions-to-deploy-with-sharepoint-add-ins